# Stock Broker Company Agreement

Tags: contract-law

Where can one check that the agreement made and sent to any client by a stock broker genuine and legal?

Comment: This question is extraordinarily broad, and does not state a country or jurisdiction, or a company you want to check. The answers will almost certainly be correspondingly broad.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the legality of an agreement by hiring a lawyer to review it for you.

You can confirm that an agreement is genuine by contacting the broker that supposedly issued it.